# Optimize query without using Temp tables and to optimize user experience

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

**Situation:**

I am new to this but just figured out how to create table-valued functions and stored procedures. I created a few for a client. I am running into an issue when I created a table-valued function with a parameter date. Within the query itself, there are a few CTEs. When the function is executed, the query loads forever and eventually I have to stop it (see below for an example).

So I divided the CTEs into 2 main `temp` tables and a query that loads the temp table. Somehow, this performs way better (see below for an example).

**Objective:**

What options do I have where the user doesn't have to run the temp tables manually. It should also be easy for the user to execute the query like stored procedures or functions.

**Example:**

I had something that looked like that which was still running after an hour.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.example
    (@StartDate AS DATE)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
   RETURN
       WITH CTE AS 
       (........), 
       CTE2 AS (.....) 
       SELECT *  
       FROM CTE2 ... 
       JOINS...
```

So I created temp tables instead which performed very well:

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATE = ....
SELECT * INTO #cte FROM (query) temp1

DECLARE @StartDate AS DATE = ....
SELECT * INTO #cte2 FROM (query) temp1

SELECT * 
FROM #cte2.... 
JOIN ....
```

What are my alternatives?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you use a function instead of a view?

Comment: @JaimeDrq . . . Because views cannot take arguments.

Comment: @JaimeDrq The user needs to pass arguments.

Comment: if your @StartDate corresponds with some field, you can freely filter the view by that argument.

Comment: sure, but the view doesn't optimize performance, I dnt have permissions either to create indexes on views. It will perform just as fast if not worse than the function I initially created

Comment: I'm not sure that anyone can help you with the information provided. A whole lot of things can be happening in the CTEs but the impact is reduced once you divide the queries into temp tables. Unless you're willing to share specifics (actual query, execution plan, tables and indexes definitions) it's impossible to give real advice.

Comment: @LuisCazares I understand.I wanted to know if there were other alternatives that what i've already tried that could have the same if not better performance than temp tables without compromising the user's experience

Comment: A TVF doesn't have statistics available, so sql do some assumptions that can be wrong. In the other hand, the view is able to use those statistics. I don't know what kind of arguments are you sending different than filters.